# Использование Lazy в WCF

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, веб-программирование, lazyloading

Допустим, служба передает переменную, которая имеет свойство, которое помечено, как Lazy.

При обращении к свойству c Lazy что произойдет?

WCF служба без дополнительного кода сама подгрузит недостающие данные или необходимо писать дополнительную логику?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Магии не бывает. Среда не сможет сериализовать объект, которого поля помечены как Lazy, ведь Lazy - несериализуемый тип.